# Which technologies are currently known for building quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Which approaches/technologies are currently known for building quantum gates? Apparently, there are different methods proposed in different methods in different papers for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: qubit_technologies]
It depends on which technology you use to make your Qubits.

When using trapped ions for example, laser pulses are used to manipulate states of the electrons (qubit).

Additionally certain patterns and wavelengths of these pulses makes the neighbouring ions collide and interact in logical ways. These are your "gates".